# How to build a nested tree with ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm using ASP.NET Web API 2 for the backend and AngularJS for the frontend. I want to display a treeview in AngularJS.

So I need a nested Model in my ASP Web API. The model currently looks like this:

```
public class Register
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Register> Children { get; set; }
}
```

and the controller like this:

```
    // GET: api/Registers
    public IQueryable<Register> GetRegister()
    {
        return db.Register;
    }
```

In my Database I added following examples:

[image: DBExample]

The JSON Output shows:

```
[{"ID":4,"Name":"RootFolder","Children":[{"ID":5,"Name":"Sub1","Children":null}]},{"ID":5,"Name":"Sub1","Children":null}]
```

The first entry looks fine, but I don't want to output the children itself. It it possible to only output the `RootFolder` with its `Children` and not the children itself? Like this:

```
{"ID":4,"Name":"RootFolder","Children":[{"ID":5,"Name":"Sub1","Children":null}]}
```

The second problem is, when I want enter a specific Folder ID (For example `ID 4(RootFolder)`). I only get this as a response:

[image: Specific Entry]

Why there are no child elements? The controller is this one:

```
     // GET: api/Registers/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Register))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetRegister(int id)
    {
        Register register = db.Register.Find(id);
        if (register == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(register);
    }
```

Summary:

- How can I filter the Output to only show the `RootFolder`s with each children but not showing the children objects itself?
- Why there are no children when I specify a specific ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using entity framework for database operations.
For the first point, you need to filter root folder row e.g. for root Register_ID is null

```
db.Register.Where(x => x.Register_ID == null && x.ID==ID).ToList()
```

For second point to load root folder's children you can include it's navigation property, for example refer below code.

```
db.Register.Include(x => x.Children).Where(x => x.Register_ID == null).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I just have some problems I need to solve. Today I don't get any child elements (I didn't changed my code from yesterday). The strange thing is: When Register ID 4 is the child of 5 it doesn't work. When my ID 5 is the child from 4 it's working fine. So child only works when ID is greater then Register_ID. This wasn't a problem yesterday. When I fixed this I will try your suggestion but it looks very fine. Thanks for that!

Comment: Got it working fine now. But I can't use the (x => x.Register_ID == null). Register_ID is unknown by the model. I don't know why EF renamed my "Children" Object to "Register_ID" in the Database. When I use x.Children instead of Register_ID I get an Exception, that the object and list can't be compared to null.

Comment: How to do this in dapper. I have the same structure and model.